# Retrieve data from database in specific interval into a file

Tags: php, mysql

In database, I have stored data in one second interval, but I want to retrieve the stored data into a file in some particular interval entered by the user.


The data is as below:

```
TIMESTAMP   VALUES
1436846660  10
1436846661  10
1436846662  10
1436846663  10
1436846664  10
```

For user entered interval `2`, expected result is :

```
TIMESTAMP   VALUES
1436846660  10
1436846662  10
1436846664  10
```

I am using the following command to get the data from `starttime` to `stoptime`

```
SELECT
    `VALUES`
INTO
    OUTFILE 'FILEPATH'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM
    TABLENAME
WHERE
        TABLENAME.TIMESTAMP >=starttime
    AND TABLENAME.TIMESTAMP <=stoptime;
```

So, how should I modify this code to include only those data between `starttime` and `stoptime` with the particular interval. Please provide me a solution.

Comment: You are reading the data from a file, so if you need different data, you should modify / generate a different file. Or generate the data from code, but then you would only need to store the information needed to generate it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me . Interval : 2

```
SELECT
    `value`
--  ,`timestamp`
    INTO outfile 'test.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM
    `timestamp_table`
WHERE
        `timestamp` >= 1436846660
    AND `timestamp` <= 1436846670
    AND MOD( `timestamp` ,2) = 0
```

In the last line , change 2 to whatever interval you would need .

Answer (score 0):

The query selects after the half hour

```
select
     *
    ,ROUND( TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE ,'2013-07-12' ,Insert_time ) / 48 ) AS 'interval'
FROM
    TABLENAME
```